# why 0x35014541 is output of xor eax, ebx?

Tags: assembly

`why 0x35014541 is output of xor eax, ebx? xor does not shows only 1 or 0?

```
**Register**
eax = 0xffffffff
ebx = 0xcafebabe

**Code**
```

```
    xor eax, ebx
```

**Output**

> eax = 0x35014541

**Expected**

> 1

Comment: Can you explain how you got 1 as the expected answer?

Comment: It's a bitwise xor, 32 separate boolean XOR gates in parallel, one for each bit, like the  C `^` operator.  No idea how `1` would make sense as an output even if you thought the output had to be 0 or 1; both the inputs are non-zero.  Or did you think it was a horizontal xor of all the bits, like the parity flag is for the low 8 bits?  Anyway, doesn't really matter what wrong idea you had, because that's not how it works.